# Keyspace created with Astyanax is not visible by cqlsh

Tags: java, cassandra, astyanax, cqlsh

I'm using Cassandra 1.2.6 with Astyanax. I created a keyspace named DummyKeyspace with using Java. I can reach that keyspace from `cassandra-cli` but not from `cqlsh`. Why?

Here is my Java code:

```
public void createKeyspace(Cluster cluster,String KEYSPACE_NAME,String STRATEGY, String REPLICA_FACTOR) throws ConnectionException
    {
        if(cluster.describeKeyspace(KEYSPACE_NAME) == null)
        {
            KeyspaceDefinition ksDef = cluster.makeKeyspaceDefinition();

            Map<String,String> stratOptions = new HashMap<String,String>();
            stratOptions.put("replication_factor", REPLICA_FACTOR);

            ksDef.setName(KEYSPACE_NAME)
                .setStrategyOptions(stratOptions)
                .setStrategyClass(STRATEGY);

            cluster.addKeyspace(ksDef);
            System.out.println("Keyspace " + KEYSPACE_NAME + " created and added to cluster.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Keyspace " + KEYSPACE_NAME + " already existed.");
        }
    }
```

Here is the error when I tried to reach it:

```
cqlsh> USE DummyKeyspace;
Bad Request: Keyspace 'dummykeyspace' does not exist
```

Comment: Is that copypasta? How did you get bad request for 'twitter2' when you did use 'DummyKeyspace'?

Comment: oh sorry, I forgot to change that part. I usually dont use actual names of the code segments when I sharing it in public. So thats why it is there. edited.

Comment: and yes its my code not copypasta.

Comment: What does `describe keyspaces;` output in cqlsh?

Comment: output:
`DummyKeyspace  system  tempks  system_auth  tempks1  system_traces`

Comment: Okey, so we can say it is visible but not reachable.

Comment: Well, thanks to your comment, I realized that cql lowercases the keyspace name, thus I can't reach it. I tried to create keyspace with lowercase and it worked. Then looked-up for uppercase solution and here it is: `USE "DummyKeyspace"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a ticket about this ([CASSANDRA-5879](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5879)).  Maybe the intention is to use quotes, but it is unintuitive.  You can also use the `-k` command line argument to cqlsh.

Answer (score 3):

Try enclosing the keyspace within quotes `""`